# I would like to automatically produce repetitive elements that I can fill in that stays together

Tags: environments

I would like to automatically produce a  "use the following"  followed by a `\fbox` with a `\parbox`that I can fill in with text, graphs, etc.   I usually do this manually but would like to create (is it called a custom environment?) an automatic one.

Maybe something like `\usefollow{#1}` or something?   What is the best way to accomplish this?

I have included what I have to do each time I want the phrase, "Use the following to answer the next question" followed by information in a box.  Is there a way to automate the repetitiveness?
The reason I have it in a minipages is to prevent the "use the following" from being separated from the `\fbox` i.e. by a page break.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usepackage[font=scriptsize,hypcap=false]{caption}

%% make this a code. 
\newcommand\usefollow{\begin{center}\textit{Use the following information to answer the next question}\end{center}\vspace{-5pt}}

\printanswers
\graphicspath{ {./dir1/} }
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
%% I used a minipage to keep it together.  
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
\vspace{0pt}
\usefollow{}%%%This just creates the "use the following.."

\fbox{\parbox{\linewidth}{
Consider the following equation or graph.%%inside I could put anything, graph, minipage etc.  
}}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill\\
%% I want it all in one.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lrbox` to store an environment's content and print it later.

Precautions are taken so that the text above the box is not detached at a page break by using `\\*`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usepackage[font=scriptsize,hypcap=false]{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newsavebox{\usefollowbox}
\newenvironment{usefollow}
 {%
  \par % be sure to be between paragraphs
  \addvspace{\topsep}% some vertical space
  \begin{lrbox}{\usefollowbox}
  \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}
 }
 {%
  \end{minipage}
  \end{lrbox}
  \begingroup % to confine the effect of \centering
  \centering\itshape 
  Use the following information to answer the next question\\*[3pt]% no page break
  \fbox{\usebox{\usefollowbox}}\par
  \endgroup
  \addvspace{\topsep}
}

\printanswers
\graphicspath{ {./dir1/} }

\begin{document}

\begin{usefollow}
Consider the following equation or graph.
\[
a^2+b^2=c^2
\]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{center}
and finish up.
\end{usefollow}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `environ` package to define an environment that collects your hint and packs it into your surrounding commands.

```
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{hint}{%
  \begin{center}\itshape
    Use the following information to answer the next question
  \end{center}\vspace{-5pt}
  \fbox{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{\BODY}}%
}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{hint}{%
  \begin{center}\itshape
    Use the following information to answer the next question
  \end{center}\vspace{-5pt}
  \fbox{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{\BODY}}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{hint}
Consider the following equation or graph.%%inside I could put anything, graph, minipage etc.  
\end{hint}
\end{document}
```